# Trouble converting dynamic variable to class

Tags: c#, ajax

I'm using ajax to determine when a drop down list value is changed and I pass the values of 3 drop down lists to a method to determine the price. I made the parameter dynamic and I created a class to hold the data but in the getNewPrice method, I'm getting a null when I try to access the var item information. I'm still pretty new to this stuff but I get the concept and I'm confused on how to convert the dynamic variable back to strings so I can access the information.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#documentTypeList').change(function () {
        var modelData = {
            documentType: $("#documentTypeList").val(),
            urgency: $("#urgencyList").val(),
            numberOfPages: $("#numberOfPagesList").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: modelData,
            url: "/Home/getNewPrice",
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {
                 document.getElementById('priceLabel').innerHTML = data.currentPrice;
            }
    });
    });

    public class modelData
    {
        public string documentType { get; set; }
        public string numberOfPages { get; set; }
        public string urgency { get; set; }
    }

    public JsonResult getNewPrice(modelData dropdownValues)
    {
        decimal currentPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dropdownValues.urgency);
        // do something with value and return a decimal
        return Json(new { currentPrice = currentPrice }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: what's the benefit of dynamic here? You're just casting it right away

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with ajax and the dynamic type was the only thing I could think of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model binder needs to know your specific type. It loops through properties and assigns values.

Try

```
 url: '/Home/getNewPrice',
 data: modelData

public JsonResult getNewPrice(modelData dropdownValue)
{
    //...
    return Json(new { currentPrice = currentPrice }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

document.getElementById('priceLabel').innerHTML = data.currentPrice;
```

Comment: I ran the code that you suggested and it is recognizing the modelData class now which is good but it doesn't seem to be passing the dropdown values because all values in the class are null. I updated my new code above

Comment: The success callback needs to pass in data: `success: function (data) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

i have used the javascript serializer in the past. use the deserialize() function.
more specifically => c#

```
    var list = serializer.Deserialize<List<GetJson>>(Request.Form["dataDetails"].ToString());

    internal class GetJson{
        public string variable1 {get;set;} //add your properties here
    }

Javascript
                    $.fn.serializeObject = function () {
                        var o = {};
                        var a = this.serializeArray();
                        $.each(a, function () {
                            if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                                }
                                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                            } else {
                                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                            }
                        });
                        return o;
                    };

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "url",
                         dataType: "json",
                         data: {
                            DataDetails: "[" + JSON.stringify($("#form1").serializeObject()) + "]"
                                },
```

if you need it to be more dynamic you can use the dynamic type.

```
var list = serializer.Deserialize<List<dynamic>>(Request.Form["dataDetails"].ToString());
```